# video upload with paperclip to a fold by path but can not show in view by url ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, video, path, paperclip

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :vi
has_attached_file :vi, :whiny => false,
    :url => "/uploads/videos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/uploads/videos/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension",   
    :styles => { 
    :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv' },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
   }

  validates_attachment_presence :vi
end
```

then in my view I use to show the vidoe

```
<%= video_tag vid.vi.url , :size => "320x240", :controls => true%>
```

but the video can not display.
Am I writing the correct url?how show the videos from the path I designed?
Anyone can help? appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [video_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_path) instead of video_tag.